# Value of a Short type variable

Tags: c++, output, short

the code is this:

```
 short x=30;
 short y=32760,z;
 z= x+y;
 int w= z*z;
 cout<< " w = "<< w << " z= " << z;
```

and the output is this: 
 w = 1072300516 z= -32746

## **WHY IS THIS SO?**

Comment: max short is 32768. You got an overflow, resulting in -32746. int is bigger than short, thats why w does not overflow

Comment: But why the negative sign and why this random value? Any calculations behind it?

Comment: Because of the bit representation. The highest bit specifies if the the value is positive or negative. E.g 1001 is negative and 0001 positive. If your value is already big ( 011111111) and you add a value you get an overflow resulting in a negative number ( 0111 + 0011 = 1010 )

Comment: Also no yelling please!!

Answer (score 1):

The maximum amount a `short` can hold is 32767. When you add 32760 and 30, you get 32790, which is more than the amount `short` can hold. So an overflow occurs and your number "wraps" around. That's the reason you get a negative number for z.

```
–32768 --- 0 --- 32767
```

If you think about the `short` this way, you'll understand it. When the number is too large, it goes to the negative side again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 z= x+y;      <<<<< 32790 is beyond the grasp of short
```

This would result in an overflow as you are crossing the maximum value a short can take.

Comment: So the output value is basically a garbage value? there's no calculation behind it?

Comment: @FariyaTasleem No it's well defined.